# JS : How to check if given date is within 2 years from today?

Tags: javascript, date, date-difference

If I have a date time in milliseconds, how do I check if its within 2 years of today in JavaScript ? So far, I have the following:

```
var yearInMs = ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 52 );
var givenTime = 1519183763504;
var diff =  givenTime - ( new Date().getTime());
diff = diff / yearInMs;
if( diff > 2 )
   alert('more than 2 years');
```

Is this correct ? How do account for things like leap years ?

Comment: You will need to look up how leap years are found and account for it

Comment: Save yourself (and your users) some headaches and look into https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Or more simplier [comparing old date vs today](https://jsfiddle.net/qg4f3jLu/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Just at 2 years to today and see if it's greater than the supplied date or time value, e.g.

```js
var d = new Date();
d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() + 2);

if (d > 1519183763504) {
  console.log('within  2 years')
} else {
  console.log('Not within  2 years')
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how this code accounts for leap years ?

Comment: It simply adds 2 years to the current date. If the current date is 29 February 2020, it will end up on 1 March 2022. If you want 28 February 2022 instead, it's a simple fix. How leap years are treated is usually an administrative business rule (e.g. when does someone born on 29 Feb turn 18, some say 28 Feb, others 1 March).

Comment: @JennaMaiz—oh, note also that time values are treated as UTC, so you might have timezone offset issues to deal with too.