# How to calculate if a date falls within three years from now?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, extjs, time

How do I check if a given date falls within 3 years from now. For example, if 02/23/2020 is given in milliseconds, 1582434000000, how can I check if it falls within 3 years from now ? I attempted the following,

```
//returns true if supplied date is 3 or less years from now
//false otherwise
var f = function( date )
{
    var now = new Date();
    date = new Date( date );

    if( now.getFullYear() + 3 < date.getFullYear() )
        return false;
    else if( now.getFullYear() + 3 === date.getFullYear() )
    {
        if( now.getMonth() < date.getMonth() )
            return false;
        else if ( now.getMonth() === date.getMonth() )
        {
            if( now.getDate() < date.getDate() )
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I only care about the date(time is not considered). So if today is 02/21/2018, then any time on 02/21/2021 is valid. Is this correct ? Is there a cleaner way to do tackle this problem ? I unfortunately cannot use external libraries like Moment.js(I can use ExtJS which is what I am writing my app in)

Comment: Duplicate of [*How to check if given date is within 2 years from today?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897780/js-how-to-check-if-given-date-is-within-2-years-from-today) Just add 3 years to todays date and see if it's greater than the provided date.

Answer (score 1):

It's clearer to just add some years to `now`:

```js
function check(date) {
  var now = new Date();
  var inThreeYears = new Date(now.setFullYear(now.getFullYear() + 3));
  
  return date < inThreeYears;
}

console.log(check(new Date(2019, 0, 1))); //true
console.log(check(new Date(2024, 0, 1))); //false
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a start, although it won't account for leap years, time zones, leap seconds, and various other date oddities. In that sense it is a crude solution. 
Basically, I convert "now" to the start of today (at midnight), and convert the future date to start of that day (at its midnight). The see if the difference is less than 3 years worth of milliseconds.

```
function checkDateDiff(futureDate) {
        //get current date's midnght
        var now = new Date();
        var nowStart = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());

        //get future date's midnight
        var newDate = new Date(futureDate);
        //get midnight on future date, plus one whole day (because you said you want to account for any time *on* the future date)
        var futureStart = new Date(newDate.getFullYear(), newDate.getMonth(), newDate.getDate()) + 8.64e+7;

        return futureStart - nowStart < 9.461e10;
    }
```

Comment: I guess the real question here is what is the definition of year you want to use. If a year is defined as 365 days, the question is easy

Comment: Not all days are 24 hours long where daylight saving is observed, so adding 8.64e+7 milliseconds may not be one day. Years are also of different lengths, so 9.461e10 is not suitable either (and represents 365.007716 days per year, a strange number).

Comment: @RobG I said in my answer that it doesnt account for time/date oddities, (implied that that included DST). The date milliseconds are directly from google (1 year to milliseconds). Again it is a start, and depends on how you define a "year"